# Create Camera Stream Source and connect it to jsx

Tags: javascript, html, camera, video-streaming, jsx

This is the code that I have.

```
return (
        <VideoFeedSection className='some-space'>
            <h2>Video Feed - classroom 1</h2>
            <iframe allowFullScreen
                    title = 'camera feed'
                    webkitallowfullscreen
                    mozallowfullscreen
        // !!! TO CHANGE !!!
                    src="//:0"
                    frameBorder="0"
                    width="100%"
                    height="576" />
        </VideoFeedSection>
);
```

I want to change `src="//:0"` To an actual camera source, how would I do that?
(I WANT TO MAKE A CAMERA SOURCE THEN CONNECT IT!)